# How to reference to a counter? (textual reference) at LyX

Tags: hyperref, cross-referencing, lyx

Assume that I have a counter `c` and when he came to the value of 6 (for example) I put a label "BlaBla" (i.e.: `C:six`).
Now, when I'm trying to to put a link to the counter (a reference) - I got the number "6" (at the pdf file) but if I ask for textual reference (like I mark at the picture, don't pay attention to other data there...), I got the name of the part/section/... of where I put the label and not `BlaBla` as I put at the label.

[image]

Do you know how to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: A textual reference is the name of the part/section whatever. I don't think any of the reference formats return the label itself (because you basically never want that, I think).

Comment: Thank you @TorbjørnT. - but it possible to make one like this?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Get the cross reference to return `foo` in the label `c:foo`, where `foo` can be any word. Or get the cross reference to return the textual version of the number, i.e. `one`, `two`, `three` etc., instead of `1`, `2`, `3` etc..

Comment: @TorbjørnT. - I wasn't clear enough: _Get the cross reference to return foo in the label c:foo, where foo can be any word_ - this!!

Comment: I actually have no idea how to do that.  But I think you have a greater chance of getting an answer if you can make a minimal working example (https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4488/) showing how you set up and use the counter. Add the LaTeX code and/or the `.lyx` file.

Comment: But I can't post something that I don't know how to do...

Comment: I didn't ask you to either. You can post what you have, but with a normal cross reference instead of the new type of cross reference you want to have. (I  have to say I don't really understand the purpose of this, but that is another thing altogether.)

Comment: For your question: I thought to do something like dictionary, that the counter is for the values (of course is not this, but this can explain to you why I need it...). And I don't want to do this as part of _sections, subsections..._